# rails console say "Table doesn't exist" but it shows up in my schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I am creating a join table for Equipment and Instructors called EquipmentOwnership.

```
class EquipmentOwnership < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :equipment_id, :instructor_id, :owned

  belongs_to :equipment
  belongs_to :instructor
end
```

It shows up in my schema as follows:

```
create_table "equiment_ownerships", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer "equipment_id"
  t.integer "instructor_id"
  t.boolean "owned"
end
```

However, here's what happens in the rails console:

```
[1] pry(main)> EquipmentOwnership
=> EquipmentOwnership(Table doesn't exist)
```

What are possible reasons it could be doing this?

I'm using Postgres, rails 3.2, ruby 1.9.3p194, and OSX mountain lion.

Comment: Have you run your migrations? `rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`create_table "equiment_ownerships"` is missing a `p`. So, should be:
`create_table "equipment_ownerships"`

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't catch that...  Thanks.